# Assembly.GetType fails for some reason?

Tags: c#

I have a class named "ClassA" located in my solution (called "Serenity") but I can't seem to get the type from the location I'm providing.

```
Type implementedType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("Serenity.Maple.Game.Life.Implementation" + lifeDatum.lifeid.ToString());
```

This is how the solution looks like: http://puu.sh/5XfI9.png.

However, it fails. The namespace on those classes is like so:

```
namespace Serenity.Maple.Game.Life.Implementation
```

Why does it fail? Thanks. By fail I mean it can't find it..

Comment: I would love to know what `lifeDatum.lifeid.ToString()` produces.

Comment: The life's ID to string.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure there is a `.` between the namespace name and the type name. Try this:

```
Type implementedType = Assembly
    .GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetType("Serenity.Maple.Game.Life.Implementation." + lifeDatum.lifeid.ToString());
//                                             added ^
```